# iOS how to get facebook friends(Both already logged into the app and non-logged into app) userIds?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

My app has login with Facebook. And it is about dealing with share on facebook and invite friends to my app. Previously there is "me/friends" API to get all the friends list with userids, but now it is giving only app used friends(i.e the list of friends who are already login to the app) list. So i changed to me/taggable_friends API. It is giving complete friends list But it is giving taggable id, which is not constant. I want the friends userid. Is there any way to get the friends(both already logged in users and non-logged in users) UIds?

Answer (score 1):

`taggable_friends` is for tagging friends only. You are not supposed to use it for anything else. It is not possible to get all friends anymore if it´s not for tagging or inviting (which is only available for canvas games).

More information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Comment: Ok it seems no such way to get all the friends userids.ryt?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @luschn... But i am not finding any API to get the list of all friends with their UserIds. They are providing the userId only if the user has already login into my app.

Comment: that is exactly what i am trying to tell you.